# Django static files not loading for all pages except index page

Tags: django, django-static

I am working on a blog website in django, where I can write articles.
While developing I am simultaneously hosting it on pythonanywhere.com
In dev server everything works perfect, but after deploying, I am facing a strange issue. My static files are loading for home page but are giving error-404 for all remaining pages.

While debugging, I found that for home page it searches files in path www.asdf.pythonaywhere.com/static which is correct
But for a page say 'www.asdf.pythonaywhere.com/article/1/' it searches for static files in ''www.asdf.pythonaywhere.com/article/1/static' which is incorrect.
I searched everywhere on the internet but couldn't find answer.

Here are my settings:

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

This is how I am referring to static files:

```
<link href="{% static "vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Have you added `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of every template that uses static?

Comment: Yes, I am using {% load static %} at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are using relative addressing for your static_url and root. change it to this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

add '/' before your static urls

Comment: OMG it worked! I was scratching my head for an hour for this.
So, does Django treats path as relative if not preceded by a '/' ?

Comment: It's not django. That's html. If you don't put any / before your path, It will be added to the currest url path (that's what a relative path is :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: any time my friend.